# "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals." is stopping me from using ode45

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to solve a st of 2 non-linear differential equations with ode45, but keep on coming up with the subscript indices error message.  I've checked the indices on all my variables and can't find where the problem lies.

```
%Non-linear equations
%y(1) = h, y(2) = T
nl_dydt = @(t,y) [((wii+delwi)+(sii+delsi)-ro*(kappai+delkappa)*alpha*sqrt(y(1)))/(ro*A);
              ((wii+delwi)*cp*((Tii+delTi)-Tref)+(sii+delsi)*(cp*(Tboil-Tref)+Hvap+cps*((Tsii+delTsi)-Tboil))...
                -ro*(kappai+delkappa)*alpha*sqrt(y(1))*cp(y(2)-Tref))/(ro*A*y(1))] ;
y0 = [h0; T0];
%Numerical Solver
tspan = [0 10];
[tout, y_nl] = ode45(nl_dydt, tspan, y0);
```

Can anyone spot where I might be making a mistake?
The error messages which show up for ode45 are

```
Error in odearguments (line 87)
f0 = feval(ode,t0,y0,args{:});   % ODE15I sets args{1} to yp0.
```

and

```
Error in ode45 (line 115)
    odearguments(FcnHandlesUsed, solver_name, ode, tspan, y0, options, varargin);
```

Comment: My guess, the error is in `...cp(y(2)-Tref))...`. did you forget a `*` ?

Comment: I did leave a * out.  Thanks for the save